# Firebug Console Error/Warning filter settings

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I am developing a WordPress theme which will be for sale commercially. I am running the theme through some tests and checks. One thing I want to do is to check for problems with the javascript. All of the JS is running properly as far as I can tell but I notice in Firebug under console there is a possibility of ticking several filter options to show things like javascript warnings and CSS warnings etc. See image below.

My theme uses several libraries and scripts such as bootstrap, modernizr, jquery, fitvids etc. When I turn on all of these filters I find I get overwhelmed by errors ( many from these libraries and scripts, and I am not going to "fix" those ! )

... so my question is this. What is a reasonable setup for detecting errors, or to put it more plainly which of these would I typically need to have ticked, and which I would be able to get away with leaving unticked. I also wasn't able to find a list of what these options are. Some are obvious, but some are not, so if anyone knows where that is on the firebug site, *( **edit**: just found [this](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Options_Menu))* or just knows offhand I'd like to know as much as possible.

[image]

Comment: highly doubtful the errors are libraries themselves, but rather errors in your code using the library methods

Comment: Well you might be right but if so then it seems to be errors in their example code ( in the case of bootstrap anyway) ... go to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html , tick all those boxes in the FB console and you should find errors. Myself I got this ... "Firebug's log limit has been reached. 92 entries not shown." ... but really this still is background info and not my actual question. I was never particularly bothered about boostrap etc errors, it was a detail. You seem to be knowledgeable and yet you didn't take a stab at answering what I actually asked?

Comment: strange... I get mothing showing in console. I turn off "warnings" , am only concerned with errors

Comment: ... yes but that's my question! which to be concerned with? ( turn on ALL like I was saying to see what I am talking about, including strict warnings) Do you know for what reason you would turn on warnings and/or strict warnings, or some of the others?

Comment: actually jquery seem to have generated some debate on the subject over the years ... several have resolve set to wontfix and I read in one the warnings should be ignored see this search ... https://www.google.ie/search?q=jquery+bug+trac+strict+warnings&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=gJ1&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&spell=1&q=jquery+bug+tracker+strict+warnings&sa=X&ei=D-cWUc7zIca3hAeSzYDgAw&ved=0CCsQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42080656,d.ZG4&fp=9b85d8fa27394cbd&biw=1600&bih=787

Comment: i do a lot of jQuery work.. ignore warnings. I have them turned off and they never help my debugging